# How to import data from the PM4 rowing device

Tags: python

I have a concept 2 model D rower, and I wanted to know if it was possible for me to import that data onto my computer (I have a Mac and a Windows machine) and use it in a python 2.7.3 program. Are there any libraries available to help me do this, and if so, which would be the best one to use? I need the data to allow my program to help me understand my progress in the 2,000m and 500m rowing times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear you can. According to [their site](http://www.concept2.com/service/software/concept2-utility/how-to-use/transferring-workouts-to-spreadsheet) if you transfer your workout to a spreadsheet format it's exported as a comma separated value (csv) file. You can then use Python's [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module to read in the data.

NOTE: I haven't tried this myself and don't have the equipment/data file to test this. Your mileage may vary.